# Shell Script To Only Run If $HOSTNAME Is Empty?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script that ONLY runs if $HOSTNAME is empty (for example on a node that has zeroized). However, even when the host-name has already been set the if condition of my code keeps running. Have I missed something?

```
$HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "" ]; then
    logger "STARTING sleep 120s to complete boot process"
    sleep 120
    logger "AFTER 120s"
    logger "STARTING configuration using script"
    /usr/sbin/cli -c '
    configure;
    #Configuration changes happen here
    commit'
else
    echo "No changes were made"
fi
```

Comment: How are you setting `HOSTNAME`? (Or maybe more relevantly, how are you *preventing* `HOSTNAME` from being set, depending on what shell you are using?)

Comment: @chepner i've tried using $HOSTNAME = $(hostname). The hope was that if it is empty then the "if" statement runs and makes a configuration change on the node. Otherwise nothing should happen.

Comment: It should be `HOSTNAME=$(hostname)` (no `$` before `HOSTNAME`, no spaces around the `=`). If you are using `bash`, `HOSTNAME` is already set.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought variables ALWAYS had to have the $.

Comment: Not in shell (unlike Perl and, I think, PHP); a `$` prefixed to a parameter name signals a parameter *expansion*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to assign a variable in bash you don't need to use a dollar `$`.
Secondly, to check condition in an if statement you must use `==` instead of `=`.
And finally, it's better to check length of the string, instead of comparing to `""`. You can do it by using `-z` option.
Here's fixed code:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
if [ -z "$HOSTNAME" ]; then
    logger "STARTING sleep 120s to complete boot process"
    sleep 120
    logger "AFTER 120s"
    logger "STARTING configuration using script"
    /usr/sbin/cli -c '
    configure;
    #Configuration changes happen here
    commit'
else
    echo "No changes were made"
fi
```